# calling controller method in directive works with scope but not with attrs?

Tags: angularjs, directive

I want to call a method of a controller after the directive done the change in DOM  but it was not working so i send that method in directive which being called inside a `scope.$watch`

```
.directive('checkThis', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myData: '=',
            dirty: '=',
            what: '@',
            callback: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('myData', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                    if (newValue) {
                        scope.dirty++;
                    } else { 
                        scope.dirty--;
                    }
                    check();
                }
            });

            var check = function () {
                if (angular.isDefined(scope.callback)) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        console.log('being called');
                        scope.callback();
                    }, 0, false);
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

and using this directive in HTML as below

```
<check-this my-data="vm.encryption" dirty="vm.dirty" what="column" callback="vm.checkAll()"></check-this>
```

now when I use `attrs.callback` it's not getting executed but `scope.callback()` is executed even when i check `attrs.callback` it display the method in console.

why this behaviour so?

even I tried `scope.$eval(attrs.callback)` and

```
 scope.$apply(function() { 
    scope.$eval(attrs.callback); 
 });
```

but it's not getting called. I am taking reference from [this article](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750)

Answer (score 0):

Angular directive `attrs` are strings, so calling `attrs.callback` is the string `'vm.checkAll()'` in your example. Using `$eval` can work but it is not recommended as it can be harmful to your application's security.

The solution is to use `scope.callback()`, is there some reason you don't want to use that?

If for some reason you absolutely need to use `attrs.callback`, you can use `scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.callback);` or `eval('scope.$parent.' + attrs.callback)`, because these will evaluate `vm.checkAll()` in the parent scope.

`scope.$eval(attrs.callback)` will not work because your directive is using isolate scope.

Comment: You can just call `scope.$eval(attrs.callback)`; no need to concatenate `$scope.` in there.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. While you were not completely correct (need `$parent` because of isolate scope), you did help me realize my mistake. The answer has been fixed.